# Highlight cells that meet criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I just started using VBA and need some guidance.
Aim: Highlight cells upon this 4 conditions. All conditions have to be applied

1. Same Date
2. Same Name
3. Diff Address
4. Overlapping timing

   example:

   `data 1> start time: 09:00 end time: 09:35`

   `data 2> start time: 09:20 end time: 10:00`

   `When the start time of the second data overlaps with the end time of the 
      first data, it should be highlighted

Sample data:

[image: Sample data]

Sample Otput:

[image: Click here for output]

What I have done already:

```
 Sub HighlightCells()
    Dim cel As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim clr As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    clr = 3

    For Each cel In rng
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel) > 1 Then
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
           cel.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
           clr = clr + 1
         Else
           cel.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, rng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
         End If
       End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 End Sub
```

It only highlights the duplicate in the first column

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting?

Comment: My project requires me to do it in VBA and also because i want it to be automated:)

Comment: and conditional formatting does not allow me to see the overlapping timing i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is include all 5 columns, then this should work...

```
 Sub HighlightCells()
    Dim cel As Range 'I think you want range for better functionality.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim clr As Long
    Dim AdditionalColumnsToHighlight As Integer

    AdditionalColumnsToHighlight = 4 ' means 5 columns total

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    clr = 3

    For Each cel In rng
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel) > 1 Then
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
           Range(cel, cel.Offset(0, AdditionalColumnsToHighlight)).Interior.ColorIndex = clr 'this allows you to make the range as many columns over as specified above.
           clr = clr + 1
         Else
           Range(cel, cel.Offset(0, AdditionalColumnsToHighlight)).Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, rng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
         End If
       End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the code. It works but there is a problem where it highlights the row if it is the same date and overlapping timing but does not check if the name is the same and address is different. Do you have any idea how I should code that. Thank you!

Comment: Since I've already answered your problem of, "It only highlights the duplicate in the first column" perhaps you might want to accept the answer and post a new question which clearly illustrates your issue? It's a bit impolite to string people along to answer more questions until your entire project is done correctly. I'll be happy to review a new question you post after you accept this answer. Best of luck.